# Pandas - question about Groupby - 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to print 2 columns against one another to see how much one depends on the other i.e how chances of admission depends on research experience - print the average chance of admit against research.
I'm not sure I'm getting the command correct and if size or something else should be used at the end:

```
df.groupby(['Chance of Admit', 'Research']).size()
```

this is the result when I run the above:

```
Chance of Admit  Research
0.34             0            2
0.36             0            1
                 1            1
0.37             0            1
0.38             0            2
                             ..
0.93             1           12
0.94             1           13
0.95             1            5
0.96             1            8
0.97             1            4
Length: 99, dtype: int64
```

Comment: You should show what you expect/are hoping to get out.

Comment: aren't you just looking for a regression mode of some kind? I'm not sure what you mean by print average chance against research. Regression will determine their relationship

Answer (score 0):

To see the mean admission rate by number of research papers, you should group by 'research' and take the mean:

```
df.groupby('Research').mean()
```

To see additional stats grouped by the number of research papers, use `.describe()`:

```
df.groupby('Research').describe()
```

Finally, it may be useful to plot a correlation of the chance of admission vs. the amount of research:

```
df.plot.scatter(x='Research', y='Chance of Admit')
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically speaking, to take the mean of the chance to admit column grouped by research, all you need is the following:

```py
df[['Chance of Admit', 'Research']].groupby('Research').mean()
```

But be wary here, as the number may not actually tell you what the chance of getting admitted is given a particular amount of research. That is because you don't know the denominators in those probabilities.

For example,
Suppose I had a dataset that contained the following two rows:

Chance of Admit  Research
0.75             1
0.25             1

The 'mean' "chance of admit" for research==1 would be .50 when calculated this way, but suppose that the first change came from a population of 100 students where 75% (75) we admitted. And the second from a population of 900, where 25% (225) were admitted.

Then over all the data we have, we would see 300 with research==1 admitted from a total of 1000 students or 30% change to admit with reseach==1